# How to setup Selenium Grid with Selenium 3

Tags: selenium

Below is the details where I have got exceptions as below :

When I start the node by using the below command it gives me the error like below :

```
F:\SeleniumGrid\Jars>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role webdriver -hub http://HubIpAddress:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=”firefox”, version=ANY, platform=VISTA, maxInstances=5 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver.exe
```

> Exception in thread “main” com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter ‘version=ANY,’ but no main parameter
>     was defined
>     at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.getMainParameter(JCommander.java:914)
>     at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:759)
>     at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
>     at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
>     at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.(JCommander.java:210)
>     at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$3.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:231)
>     at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:130)
>     at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:67)

Please let me know if am done anything wrong in the above command.

Below is the java code used:

```
package com.test.grid;

import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class SelGrid {




    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl, nodeURL, hubURL;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
    hubURL = "http://HubIpAddress:4444/wd/hub";

    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);


    driver = new RemoteWebDriver (new URL(hubURL), capability);

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest()
    {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Assert.assertEquals("Welcome: Mercury Tours", driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the order you call the -Dwebdriver param in Selenium 3. To avoid the issue, make sure -Dwebdriver is always before the -jar call. You will need to add the hub registration and node configurations in the nodeConfig.json.

```
F:\SeleniumGrid\Jars>java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
```

Example nodeConfig

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Source:
http://jjtheengineer.blogspot.com/2016/12/selenium-grid-30-setup-migrating-from.html

Answer (score 0):

Few things which might solve your issues:

1. From selenium 3 you have to use the geckodriver driver to be able to use firefox. You need download the [geckodriver driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Also inside your code add(inside your capabilities section):

   ```
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
   ```
2. When you register your node to the hub use the following as is:

   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub  http://HubIpAddress:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=”firefox”, version=ANY, platform=VISTA, maxInstances=5

Answer (score -2):

I worked on grid multiple times and I faced the same issue with Beta version. Can you try with Selenium 2.53.1 or any other previous version.

http://learn-automation.com/selenium-grid-for-remote-execution/

Comment: The whole idea of this problem is to work with Selenium 3 where it will use geckodriver and make it compatible to Selenium grid, answers related to this problem statement is welcomed.